# join two csv files by using one column matching multiple columns

Tags: linux, csv, join, awk, grep

I need to use column 2 in file1 to compare to columns 15, 17, 18, 19, 20 from file2. If there is a match on either one of columns listed from file2, I want to write to a file that has column 2 from file1, followed by column 3, 4 from file 2

both file1 and file2 are csv files. file1 has around 66 k rows and file2 has around 66 million rows.

here are example rows for file1

```
    head,user1,12345
    head,user2,52412
    head,user1,83712
```

example rows for file2

```
    row1:bla1,bla2,row1foo,row1bar,bla5,bla6,bla7,bla8,bla9,bla10,bla11,bla12,bla13,bla14,user1, , , , , , 

    row2:bla1,bla2,row2foo,row2bar,bla5,bla6,bla7,bla8,bla9,bla10,bla11,bla12,bla13,bla14, , , , , user2 , , \n
    row3: bla1,bla2,row3foo,row3bar,bla5,bla6,bla7,bla8,bla9,bla10,bla11,bla12,bla13,bla14,user3, , , , , , \n
    row4:bla1,bla2,row4foo,row4bar,bla5,bla6,bla7,bla8,bla9,bla10,bla11,bla12,bla13,bla14, , , , , , user9, \n               

    row5:bla1,bla2,row5foo,row5bar,bla5,bla6,bla7,bla8,bla9,bla10,bla11,bla12,bla13,bla14,user1, , , , ,user1, \n
```

the result I want to see is:

```
    ...
    user1,row1foo,row1bar\n
    user2,row2foo,row2bar\n
    user1,row5foo,row5bar\n
    ...
```

apologies for the very long format of file2

Comment: Do the matches need to be line by line, or if column 2 in file1 matches ANY line in file2?

Comment: column 2 in file1 matches ANY of column15, 17,18,19,20 from file2 would be considered a match

Comment: The question was whether column 2 on line 5 from file1 needs to match line 5 from file2 or whether it can match on any line from file2.

Comment: Including example (simplified) data and expected output VS current output + your attempt to code a solution for your problem are the most reliable way of eliminating multiple questions back and forth about the definition of the problem. Good luck.

Comment: In last record of file2, there are two "user1" matched, do you need export for two records or only one, if there are two matched with different users, then what's your expect output?

Answer (score 1):

For Gnu Awk version 4, you can use `FPAT` to read CSV data. You can try the following:

```
gawk -f cmp.awk file1 file2 > file3
```

where `cmp.awk` is

```
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    OFS=","
}
NR==FNR {
    if (NF>1) a[$2]++
    next
}
{
    for (i in a)
        if ($15==i || $17==i || $18==i || $19==i || $20==i)
            print i,$3,$4
}
```

Comment: interesting, is cmp.awk a file I should create individually?

Answer (score 0):

Very quickly, this would be something easier done in Ruby or Perl.

However, if the files aren't too large you could read them both into arrays and then use a series of loops to look for matches.  If you find any, print the array indexes you want.

If the data sets are exceptionally large (which I think you've indicated they are), you may want to consider using a database to hold all the data.  Read the files into separate database tables, and then use Ruby/Perl/Whatever to process the data and store the appropriate results in a third table.

Either way, the same logic would apply... grab a row from file/table1, now iterate through file/table2 looking for any matches in the specified columns.  If you find one, copy the data to a third file/table.

Comment: thanks, apologies for not mentioning the sizes of the files. they are pretty big, file1 has 66 k rows and file2 has around 66 million rows, but sure ruby would be a good choice from the performance point of view. is there anything quicker and simple that we can use from the bash level?

Comment: With that much data to parse, you're really not going to want to use bash.  It's not well suited (nor intended) for the type of work you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk -F , 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}                 # Read file1 column 2 into array a.
          {  for (i=15;i<=20;i++)             
                 { gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",$i)      # Remove useless blank space 
                   if (i!=16&&$i in a)        # compare option #1, not column 16, option #2, $i column is found in array a, 
                      print $i FS $3 FS $4  
                 }
          }' file1 file2
```

result

```
user1,row1foo,row1bar
user2,row2foo,row2bar
user1,row5foo,row5bar
user1,row5foo,row5bar
```